# html css styled ordered list, positioned outside and with custom counter

Tags: html, css

For an academic website, I would like to maintain a list of publications sub-divided by type (journal article, conference paper, workshop paper, etc), and uniquely numbered according to the publication type, so that I can reference them throughout the website.

```
Margin | Body
       |
       | ## Conference Papers
  [C1] | Conference paper 1
  [C2] | Conference paper 2
       |
       | ## Journal Articles
  [J1] | Journal Article 1
```

I would like the numbering to appear in the margin. I can achieve this by using the `list-style-position:outside;` attribute. However, this won't work if I use the `list-style: none;` attribute, to achieve the custom numbering (eg. C1, instead of 1.) Is it possible to position the numberings outside the main text area when using custom lists?

Edit: Code

```
ol {
    list-style: none; counter-reset: item 1;
}
ol li:nth-of-type(1){
    font-weight: normal;
}
ol li{
    list-style-position:outside;
    margin-left: 0px; 
    padding-left: 0px;
}
ol li:before {
    content: "[C" counter(item) "] "; 
    color: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>Conference Paper 1</li>
    <li>Conference Paper 2</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hzuwC/

Comment: Don't forget to add `counter-increment: item;` to your `li` (and you might also want to change your reset from `1` to `0`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also set `position: absolute` on the `before` pseudo-element and `position: relative` on the `li` and then position the former relatively to its parent.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fCKVj/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin Turjak. Your answer got me on the right track. However, your solution doesn't quite work, since it omits the counter-increment:item; attribute in the li:before. If you update your demo, I'd happily accept your answer. I omitted the counter-increment, so it's my fault, not yours.

Comment: I fixed the counter now. Before I just copied your code and edited the part relevant for the positioning of the pseudo-element. Hope that this is better now ^_^

Answer (score 4):

Try adding margin for `ol li:before`

```
ol li:before {
    content: "[C" counter(item) "] "; color: green; 
    margin-left: -1em; 
    margin-right: .65em;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/degaD/)**